# The openParentApplication call in ios does not open my parent application

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, appdelegate, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

I need to know how can I open the parent app of my iphone. I have a watch with *version 1.0.1* and the parent app has *8.4 iOS*.

This is my code in the `AppDelegate`

```
 __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bogusWorkaroundTask;
    bogusWorkaroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bogusWorkaroundTask];
    }];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bogusWorkaroundTask];
    });
    // --------------------
```

And this is the way I reply info :

```
    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"program"]) {
        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier realBackgroundTask;
        realBackgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            reply(nil);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:realBackgroundTask];
        }];
        // Kick off a network request, heavy processing work, etc.
        // Return any data you need to, obviously.
        [WatchRequestsHandler handleCurrentProgramRequestWithReply:reply];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:realBackgroundTask];

        NSLog(@"Reply :: %@ ", reply);
    } else if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"programs"]){

        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier realBackgroundTask;
        realBackgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            reply(nil);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:realBackgroundTask];
        }];
        // Kick off a network request, heavy processing work, etc.
        // Return any data you need to, obviously.
        [WatchRequestsHandler handleProgramsRequestWithReply:reply];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:realBackgroundTask];

        NSLog(@"Reply :: %@ ", reply);
    }
```

But my parent app don´t open.

What is my mistake! Help please

Comment: By open Parent App. What you mean...??

Comment: I mean that the parent App don´t open in background mode!

Comment: Select WatchKit App scheme and run the app. Now click on debug and from drop down list choose Attach process. Click on the iPhone App and attach it. now place break points in parent app and test where is the problem.